# Google Maps v3 Distance Matrix to find closest location

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I am creating a windows store application in javascript.

I have a list of locations in a JSON object array(destinations) and another array of JSON objects(origins).

I would like to click on an origin marker and use the distance matrix to find the closest destination or list of sorted destinations.

I don't want to use PHP or anything like that.

Please help me!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) is pretty neat;

```
var origin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(55.930385, -3.118425);
var origin2 = "Greenwich, England";
var destinationA = "Stockholm, Sweden";
var destinationB = new google.maps.LatLng(50.087692, 14.421150);

var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
service.getDistanceMatrix(
  {
    origins: [origin1, origin2],
    destinations: [destinationA, destinationB],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: UnitSystem,
    durationInTraffic: Boolean,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  }, callback);

function callback(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
        var element = results[j];
        var distance = element.distance.text;
        var duration = element.duration.text;
        var from = origins[i];
        var to = destinations[j];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That does make sense - and iv been using that but how do I order the results according to the smallest distance.